# Class not registered error before login screen on Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, boot

I am getting `class not registered` error even before the login screen of Windows 10, so I am not able to apply the fixes, which I found on Google, telling to fix the issue by uninstalling the program/ re-registering the required .dll file/ Check Disk, or any other fix as I cannot login in my PC.

[image: Class not registered]

On windows boot, windows is checking for disk errors in C:. After completion of disk error, windows boots us and this dialog box is coming on a black screen. What I can understand is that the Wacom's software is starting even before the login screen appears, and thus this error is coming before. Whenever I click `OK`, this dialog box reappears again and does not let me proceed to login screen.

I tried but not working:

1. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Del</kbd> - nothing happening
2. Running Reset This PC with the Keep My Files option through troubleshoot options - resetting failed
3. [EDIT] I tried booting the PC in safe mode, it was not booting, but it sometimes it rebooted with the same error and other times it took me back to blue screen.

Please can you suggest how to fix this issue?

Comment: Start the PC in safe mode and uninstall the Wacom software: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/start-your-pc-in-safe-mode-in-windows-10-92c27cff-db89-8644-1ce4-b3e5e56fe234

Comment: I tried booting the PC in safe mode, it was not booting, but it sometimes it rebooted with the same error and other times it took me back to blue screen. I'm sorry I missed mentioning it in the question.

Comment: Then I would boot into recovery console, get the command prompt and rename that nasty `C:\Program Files\Table\Wacom\Wacom_Tablet.exe` by e.g. changing the file extension to `ex_`. Then it can't be executed and should not create an error anymore.

Comment: Trying this gives the new error. It says `Windows cannot find 'C:\Program Files\Table\Wacom\Wacom_Tablet.exe'. Make sure you've typed the name correctly, then try again.

Comment: After wasting a precious day in attempts to recover the windows, I proceeded for its reinstallation. In case anyone comes up with a solution, please share it as it will help people in future issues.

Comment: Be careful with reinstalling the Wacom software. Such error can arrive when installing old or wrong software version for your Windows.

Comment: Yes, I've installed the latest version for my model from their website.